# Unable to generate output

Tags: clips

When I run the below code, it doesn't give me any output. It prints Flag  color (done to end)?.  Not sure what I am missing. Any help is appreciated.  Thank you

```
(deftemplate flag (slot country) (multislot colors))

(deffacts countries
   (flag (country USA) (colors red white blue))
   (flag (country Belgium) (colors black yellow red))
   (flag (country Poland) (colors white red)) 
   (flag (country Monaco) (colors white red)) 
   (flag (country Sweden) (colors yellow blued))
   (flag (country Panama) (colors red white blue))
   (flag (country Jamaica) (colors black yellow green))
   (flag (country Columbia) (colors yellow blue red))
   (flag (country Italy) (colors green white red))
   (flag (country Greece) (colors blue white))
   (flag (country Botswana) (colors blue white black)))

(deffacts start
   (get-color))

(defrule get-colors
   ?f <- (get-color)
   =>
   (retract ?f)
   (printout t "Flag color (done to end)?")
   (assert (new-color (read))))

(defrule find-matches
   (find-flag)
   (exists (color ?))
   (flag (country ?country))
   (forall (color ?color)
           (flag (country ?country) (colors $? ?color $?)))
   =>
   (printout t ?country " 's flag contains the specified colors." crlf))

(defrule no-matches
   (find-flag)
   (not (and (flag (country ?country))
             (forall (color ?color)
                     (flag (country ?country) (colors $? ?color $?)))))
   => 
   (printout t "No country's flag contains the specified colors." crlf))

(defrule all-flags-match
   (find-flag)
   (not (color ?))
   =>
   (printout t "No search colors were specified." crlf))

(defrule look-for-flags
   ?f <- (new-color done)
   =>
   (retract ?f)
   (assert (find-flag)))

(defrule look-for-another-color
   ?f <- (new-color ?color&~done)
   =>
   (assert (color ?color))
   (retract ?f)
   (assert (get-color)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The program is expecting you to enter one or more colors. When you've specified all of the colors, enter done at the prompt. It then prints the names of the countries that have flags containing those colors.

```
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Flag color (done to end)?red
Flag color (done to end)?done
Italy 's flag contains the specified colors.
Columbia 's flag contains the specified colors.
Panama 's flag contains the specified colors.
Monaco 's flag contains the specified colors.
Poland 's flag contains the specified colors.
Belgium 's flag contains the specified colors.
USA 's flag contains the specified colors.
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Flag color (done to end)?red
Flag color (done to end)?white
Flag color (done to end)?done
Italy 's flag contains the specified colors.
Panama 's flag contains the specified colors.
Monaco 's flag contains the specified colors.
Poland 's flag contains the specified colors.
USA 's flag contains the specified colors.
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Flag color (done to end)?red
Flag color (done to end)?white
Flag color (done to end)?blue
Flag color (done to end)?done
Panama 's flag contains the specified colors.
USA 's flag contains the specified colors.
CLIPS>
```